# How to use Deskjet 2050 J510 scanner on Scientific Linux 6.1?

Tags: scientific-linux, scanner

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=672306

So... I need to install hplip-3.11.3a-1.fc14 ? How? I can't find the rpm in the repositories, and I can't find the rpm on the net.. can someone please describe how to bring the scanner to life?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) download the RPM for RedHat 6: 
http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install_wizard/index.html

2)
Remove the old hplip packages

3)
Install the downloaded package, it works!! :)